# The suffix -sal, usage and examples

Tags: suffix

Here is an excerpt form the Book "German: An Essential Grammar":

[image]

I was surprised to see the suffix -sal, of which I had never encountered.

What is the usage of this of this suffix?

Comment: Schicksal, Trübsal (blasen), ... I don't know more of the top of my head.

Comment: +1 for umalautable :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The suffix [**-sal**](http://canoonet.eu/services/WordformationRules/Derivation/To-N/Suffixe/sal.html?lang=en) is derived from Middle High German *"-sel"* to build nouns from verbs. Resulting nouns can be of neuter or female gender.

#### Examples *(Verb > Noun)*

> laben > das/die Labsal
> scheuen > das Scheusal
> trüben > die Trübsal
> mühen > die Mühsal
> rinnen > das Rinnsal

**Curious side note:** sometimes the resulting noun is again transformed back to a verb:

> drängen > die Drangsal > drangsalieren

Comment: So how does "Schicksal" mean "fate"?

Comment: @TomAu: The root 'schick' is no more directly related to the concept of fate in contemporary German. You might consult: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schicken - in particular, "schick" as an adjective (pretty, suitable), the reflexive verb "sich schicken" (to be appropiate) and "Geschick" (roughly: ability) provide some hint to the origins of "Schicksal".

You might note that "-sal" is no more a productive suffix in general.

Comment: @Martin/@TomAu: Actually, with „Geschick“ you hit the bull's eye but got confused at the same time by its second meaning. Your translation "ability" comes from the adjectiv „geschickt“, meaning "quite skilled" or even "clever".
But the much older noun „Geschick“ is nothing less than a synonym for „Schicksal“, ergo: "Destiny". I can even dare some sophistry in finding in „Geschick“ the verb „schicken“, meaning "to send" (along), "to forward". So it all makes sense in the end, as you arrive where you are sent to, in meating your destiny. ;-) All absurdity in my text is due to my being, actually,

Comment: Grimm leitet *Schicksal* von *schicken* ab und schreibt zu letzterem: „in älterer sprache vorwiegend im sinne von ordnen, rüsten, bereiten, einrichten, fügen, ins werk setzen, bewirken, schaffen, wenden, richten“

Comment: @Martin: I think that the adjective *schick* is not cognate with *schicken* anyway, but derived from *chique*.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: its the other way round: French *chic/chique* was derived from the German *Schick*: http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chic.

Comment: @Takkat: Hah, so it seems that the word travelled to Paris and came back. I did not know that. Thanks!